# Tits construction of algebraic groups of type D₆ and E₇ via C₃

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

As shown in the Freudenthal magic square, the Tits construction of $D_6$ takes as input
an quaternion algebra and the Jordan algebra of a quaternion algebra (see *[The Book of Involutions](https://doi.org/10.1090/coll/044)* § 41). In terms of algebraic groups and Galois cohomology this is a $A_1 \times C_3$ construction.
To obtain groups of type $E_7$ one can use a quaternion algebra $Q$ and the Jordan algebra of an octonion algebra (i.e. an Albert algebra $J$), which is a $A_1 \times F_4$ construction. Due to the well known non-symmetry of the Tits construction, the other way of obtaining $E_7$ (i.e. swapping the inputs) yields a $G_2 \times C_3$ construction. Let $G$ be a split algebraic group twisted by a torsor coming from one of the  Tits constructions involving $C_3$.

**Question:** Is it possible that the output $G$ is anisotropic for certain inputs? How are those $G$ obtained?

If the resulting $D_6$ is anisotropic and the Brauer classes of the algebras involved are the same (i.e. $Q = B$, for the $C_3$ torsor $(B, \tau)$) for example, this case would be very interessting.

Comment: A context remark for other readers: The construction you mention but are not interested in, where $A_1 \times F_4$ gives an $E_7$, gives the compact (anisotropic) form of $E_7$ over the real numbers (Jacobson's book "Exceptional Lie algebras", p.116).